# NestJS/Express return PDF file from external URL in response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nestjs

I'm calling an external API that returns a PDF file and I want to return this PDF file in my controller function response.

In My controller class:

```
  @Get(':id/pdf')
  async findPdf(@Param('id') id: string, @Res() res: Response) {
    const response = await this.documentsService.findPdf(id);

    console.log(response.data); 
    // this prints the following:
    // %PDF-1.5
    // %����
    // 2 0 obj
    // << /Type /XObject /Subtype /Image /ColorSpace /DeviceRGB /BitsPerComponent 8 /Filter // /DCTDecode /Width 626 /Height
    //  76 /Length 14780>>
    //  stream
    // and go on...

    return res
      .status(200)
      .header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
      .header('Content-Disposition', response.headers['content-disposition'])
      .send(response.data);
  }
```

In My service class:

```
  findPdf(id: string): Promise<any> {
    return firstValueFrom(
      this.httpService
        .get(`/docs/${id}/pdf`)
        .pipe(map((response) => response))
        .pipe(
          catchError((e) => {
            throw new BadRequestException('Failed to get PDF.');
          }),
        ),
    );
  }
```

However I'm getting a blank PDF file in my response.

The internal API call works fine, I've tested it from Postman and the PDF file is correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why did you say that `I'm getting a blank PDF file in my response`?

Comment: @hoangdv well because the PDF file generated by my NestJS endpoint is a blank PDF file without any content on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested and reproduced the issue you are describing.

The reason is that your external server responds with PDF as a stream and your solution is not handling it.

First, since the response is the stream, you need to inform Axios about that (HTTP service) by changing:

```
.get(`/docs/${id}/pdf`)
```

to:

```
.get(`/docs/${id}/pdf`, { responseType: "stream" })
```

After that, you have two approaches (depending on what you need):

1. You can pipe that stream to your main response (hence deliver to stream to the caller of your service).
2. You can collect whole stream data from the document server and then deliver the final buffer data to the caller.

I hope this helps.

Complete source code with example is here:

```
import { HttpService } from "@nestjs/axios";
import { BadRequestException, Controller, Get, Res } from "@nestjs/common";
import { catchError, firstValueFrom, map, Observable } from "rxjs";
import { createReadStream } from "fs";

@Controller('pdf-from-external-url')
export class PdfFromExternalUrlController {

  constructor(
    private httpService: HttpService
  ) {
  }

  // Simulated external document server that responds as stream!
  @Get()
  async getPDF(@Res() res) {
    const file = createReadStream(process.cwd() + '/files/test.pdf');
    return file.pipe(res);
  }

  @Get('indirect-pdf')
  async findPdf(@Res() res) {
    const pdfResponse = await firstValueFrom(this.httpService
      .get(`http://localhost:3000/pdf-from-external-url`, { responseType: "stream" })
      .pipe(map((response) => response))
      .pipe(
        catchError((e) => {
          throw new BadRequestException('Failed to get PDF.');
        }),
      ));
    
    // APPROACH (1) - deliver your PDF as stream to your caller
    // pdfResponse.data.pipe(res);
    // END OF APPROACH (1)
    
    // APPROACH (2) - read whole stream content on server and then deliver it
    const streamReadPromise = new Promise<Buffer>((resolve) => {
      const chunks = [];
      pdfResponse.data.on('data', chunk => {
        chunks.push(Buffer.from(chunk));
      });
      pdfResponse.data.on('end', () => {
        resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks));
      });
    });

    const pdfData = await streamReadPromise;

    res.header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
    res.send(pdfData);
    // END OF APPROACH (2)
  }
}
```

Comment: I get an error on the line pdfResponse.data.on('data', chunk => {

Comment: The error is pdfResponse.data.on is not a function","level":"error"}

Comment: My pdfResponse.data looks like

data: '%PDF-1.7 \n' +
    '%���� \n' +
    '1 0 obj \n' +
    '<< \n' +
    '/Type /Catalog \n' +
    '/Pages 2 0 R \n' +
    '/PageMode /UseNone \n' +
    '/ViewerPreferences << \n' +
    '/FitWindow true \n' +
    '/PageLayout /SinglePage \n' +
    '/NonFullScreenPageMode /UseNone \n' +
    '>> \n' +
    '>> \n' +
    'endobj \n' +
    '5 0 obj \n' +
    '<< \n' +
    '/Length 2906 \n' +
    '/Filter [ /FlateDecode ] \n' +
    '>> \n' +
    'stream\n' +
    'x��XYs�6\x12~�_�c@�&A\x02�!R#k$��!�cŒ��ڑ\x13�vk�[�}���n\x1C$gFr��"G�`�����\x17�Z9

Comment: I do have a token to pass, so I had to include headers with the responseType. The axios call returns a good response, I just don't understand what is supposed to be happening where const streamReadPromise is being executed and it isn't working.

Comment: same issue with @S.Varner error:  pdfResponse.data.on is not a function

Comment: Oh, let me try the long-shot guess: Your server is not responding with the stream, but with complete PDF document binary.

This answer, is about handling stream response (where parts of the document are delivered in chunks).

Comment: But, to avoid long shots, can you build the SO question, or share example of the code you are trying to make (I will gladly try to reproduce the issue and check why error with 'on' not being a function on the stream does not exist).